# Bibtex: Compile a new style from btxbst.doc: compilation error

Tags: bibtex, compiling, compilation-error

I'm trying to follow this ressource http://linuxtoosx.blogspot.com/2010/09/bibtex-styles-alpha-abbrv-alphaabbr.html in order to change the `alpha` mode in order to display abbreviated authors like `F. Foo`.

So to do that, I downloaded the [zip from bibtex ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base.zip) and ran `cpp -P -DALPHA btxbst.doc alphaabbr.bst` to compile the style file... Which fails:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/alphaabbr/ && cd /tmp/alphaabbr/
$ wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base.zip
$ unzip base.zip
$ cd base
$ cpp -P -DALPHA btxbst.doc alphaabbr.bst
btxbst.doc:1:16: warning: missing terminating ' character
 % BibTeX `plain' family
                ^
btxbst.doc:22:13: warning: missing terminating ' character
 % If you don't have access,

[...]

btxbst.doc:421:6: error: "'mid.sentence :=" is not a valid filename
   #1 'mid.sentence :=

[...]
```

Any idea what's wrong?

cpp version: cpp (Debian 8.3.0-3) 8.3.0

PS: for completeness, the patch to apply to get alphaabbr style is:

```
+++ btxbst.doc 2010-09-16 17:14:50.000000000 +0200
@@ -95,7 +95,7 @@
 % alpha style (sorted short alphabetics)
 #   define LAB_ALPH 1
 #   define SORTED 1
-#   define NAME_FULL 1
+#   define NAME_FULL 0
 #   define ATIT_LOWER 1
 #   define MONTH_FULL 1
 #   define JOUR_FULL 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `btxbst.doc` indeed mentions to use `cpp`, the usage of a C preprocessor for BibTeX code is not fully ideal. The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) of `cpp` mentions the following:

> The C preprocessor is intended to be used only with C, C ++ , and
>   Objective-C source code. In the past, it has been abused as a general
>   text processor. It will choke on input which does not obey C's lexical
>   rules. For example, apostrophes will be interpreted as the beginning
>   of character constants, and cause errors. Also, you cannot rely on it
>   preserving characteristics of the input which are not significant to
>   C-family languages. If a Makefile is preprocessed, all the hard tabs
>   will be removed, and the Makefile will not work.
>
> Having said that, you can often get away with using cpp on things
>   which are not C. Other Algol-ish programming languages are often safe
>   (Pascal, Ada, etc.) So is assembly, with caution. **-traditional-cpp**
>   mode preserves more white space, and is otherwise more permissive.
>   Many of the problems can be avoided by writing C or C ++ style
>   comments instead of native language comments, and keeping macros
>   simple.

So the following works (there are still a lot of warnings, but no errors):

`cpp -traditional-cpp -P -DALPHA btxbst.doc alphaabbrv.bst`

Note that you still should make the change as indicated in the blog post (set `NAME_FULL 0` in line 98 of `btxbst.doc`) before compiling/preprocessing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testarta,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  pages         = {1-5},
  year          = {2010},
}

@article{testartb,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {An Uninteresting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {8},
  pages         = {1-5},
  year          = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Some citations \cite{testarta,testartb}.

\bibliographystyle{alphaabbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]